error: package androidx.navigation does not exist
I'm trying to build a "first Java app" in Android Studio.  I followed directions here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-for-android-building-your-first-android-app/#.  Those directions are not clear, but when I try to build, I get this error message:
error: package androidx.navigation does not exist

How do I resolve this?
PS. On another note, does anyone know of a website that describes a simple "Hello World" Java application in Android Studio?  For now, I just want to get any code working.

Look at the tutorial article again. I believe you were meant to type
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

whereas you typed
import androidx.navigation;

Fix your import(s).

I simply cut-and-pasted the tutorial code into the file. So, the file was and is correct: androidx.navigation.Navigation.  The error must be coming from the configuration, or my installation of Android Studio, or something else.
